# Issues with readonly and private methods

Tags: c#, constructor, readonly

"Create a program named "DemoSquare" that initiates an array of 10 Square objects with sides that have values of 1 -10 and that displays the values for each square. The Square class contains fields for the area and the length of a side, and a constructor that requires a parameter for the area and the length of a side. The constructor assigns its parameter to the length of a Square's side and calls a private method that computes the area field. Also include read-only properties to get a Squares side and area."

Now I think that it is a trick question as I can't get the private method to compute the area because of the read-only assignment but here is my code:

```
    class demoSquares
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Square[] squares = new Square[10];//Declares the array of the object type squares
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Enter the length");
                //double temp = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                squares[i] = new Square(i+1);//Initializes the objects in the array 
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(squares[i]);
            }//end for loop, prints the squares
        }//end main

      }//end class
```

This is the Square Class:

```
   public class Square
   {

    readonly double length;
    readonly double area;

    public Square(double lengths)//Constructor 
    {
       length = lengths;
       area = computeArea();
    }

    private double computeArea()//getmethod 
    {
        double areaCalc = length * length;
        return areaCalc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I got it working by making a accessor method and not declaring the area parameter as readonly but the exercise seems very specific. The chapter was about accessors and classes but I don't see why our lecturer would give use something that does not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't confuse read-only properties with read-only fields.

```
   public class Square
   {
        public Square(double lengths)
        {
           Length = lengths;
           Area = computeArea();
        }

        //Read only property for Length (privately settable)
        public double Length {get; private set;}

        //Read only property for Area (privately settable)
        public double Area {get; private set;}

        //Private method to compute area.
        private double ComputeArea()
        {
            return Length * Length;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The question mentions readonly properties, not readonly fields.

a readonly field can only be assigned in a constructor or by a field initializer. 
A readonly property can only be assigned inside the class.

```
public class Square
{
   // Readonly field, can only be assigned in constructor or initializer
   private readonly double _sideLength;

   // Readonly property since it only contains a getter
   public double SideLength { get { return _sideLength; } }

   // Readonly property from outside the class since the setter is private
   public double Area {get; private set;}

   public Square( double sideLength )
   {
        _sideLength = sideLength;
        CalcSquare();
   }

   private void CalcSquare()
   {
      this.Square = _sideLength * _sideLength;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A read-only variable can indeed be assigned in the constructor, but not in methods called from the constrctor. There are ways to do that, i.e. : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848441/assign-value-of-readonly-variable-in-private-method-called-only-by-constructors). The correct way would be to calculate the area and store the result in the area variable.

I believe, though, that the meaning was different in the question. Quoting you :

> Also include read-only properties to get a Squares side and area.

meaning, the question meant that you use `Properties`. Meaning, you would use private variables for `length` and `area`, and implement a get-only property for each :

```
public double Area 
{
    get
    {
       return area;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider how you would restructure the code if you didn't try to assign the computed area to the `area` field, but instead returned the value from `computeArea`.

As an additional exercise, try making `computeArea` static and see how that affects the code.

Comment: I see the logic there, but now when displaying that object it just shows the type when I call it in the DemoSquares class

Answer (score 0):

You assignment never said your private function should **assign** area. It said the **constructor** should assign area with the result of a private method:

```
public class Square
{
    private readonly double length;
    private readonly double area;

    public Square(double length) 
    {
        this.length = length;
        this.area = computeArea(length); // assignment of area in constructor!
    }

    private double ComputeArea(double length) 
    {
         return length * length;
    }
}
```